# c++: can I give a new value to a thread, while it is still running or do I have to end it first?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, csv

I have just started using threads when coding, and I'm not sure whether I understood properly how they work. 
If I got it right, with a thread you can make two functions run at the same time. Is it possible to change the value given to one of the functions while it is still running in parallel?
In my case I read instructions from a csv file such as:

```
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=0;      colParam1=-30;  colParam2=2;
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=10;     colParam1=-15;  colParam2=0.4;
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=0;      colParam1=-10;  colParam2=1;
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=45;     colParam1=-60;  colParam2=11;
colAction=TEMPERATURE;  colTime=120;    colParam1=95;
colAction=TEMPERATURE;  colTime=20;     colParam1=57;
colAction=TEMPERATURE;  colTime=25;     colParam1=95;
colAction=LOOP;                         colParam1=22;   colParam2=7;     colParam3=23;
colAction=TEMPERATURE;  colTime=20;     colParam1=95;
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=0;      colParam1=-10;  colParam2=11;
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=1;      colParam1=-1;   colParam2=5;
colAction=VELOCITY;     colTime=5;      colParam1=-20;  colParam2=11;
```

I have a function that sets a temperature and a function that sets a velocity. the parameter colTime tells me how long I have to hold the velocity or the temperature, without following the next instruction. when the colTime has expired, I need to follow the next instruction: if a temperature is followed by another temperatur I just give the function the next value, but if temperature is followed by velocity, I need to keep the temperature function running, while starting the velocity function. 
The problem arises, when after setting temperature then velocity follows another temperature. Now I need to keep the velocity running and setting another temperature. And I don't know how to do this.
I hope I could make my problem clear somehow and it is not too confused.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I’ll use multithreading”. Nothhw tpe yawrve o oblems.

Comment: "but if temperature is followed by velocity, I need to keep the temperature function running, while starting the velocity function." no you do not, just call temperature function and then velocity function. just make those functions return immediatly

Comment: Re, "I hope I could make my problem clear somehow..." The best way to do that is, write some code. Then, if the code doesn't do what you think it should do, you can show it here and ask people why not.

Comment: Absolutely. Passing data between threads is commonplace. Your worker thread needs to wait for input to be provided by some synchronised data container. Your question is far too broad though. Which C++ book are you using? Pick up one on multithreaded programming; this will be one of the early examples.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a process can be seen a stack of function/procedure/method calls. At any point in time your program will be in a single point of your code.

When we add multiple threads into the program, instead of a single stack, we now will have multiple stacks of function/procedure/method calls. Each of them will be at any point in time in a different points of your code.

In C/C++, your main thread (the one that started it all) will have at the bottom of the stack the `int main(int argc,char**argv)` function. That applies to both single threaded and the main thread of a multithreaded program.

How about the rest of the threads. Well, for each of them you will specify a starting function. Threads (and main threads) will start execution at the beginning of the start function and run til the end. The thread will be alive while its starting function is being executed.

Now thinking of your code. One of many possibilities is spawn a thread to execute your temperature or velocity functions. That would be your starting function for newly spawned thread. You can `join()` from the spawning thread to wait for it to complete.

The thing about threads vs. other multiprocessing ways of organizing code (e.g. heavy processes) is that although we've seen that each of the threads have its own call stack, they all share the same memory.

So, while is not possible to modify the arguments of the thread starting function (that train has already passed)... However, other parts of the code could simply change some value in the memory (which is shared) and the starting function of the thread could be *periodically checking that memory* to detect the change and modify its behaviour.

But that brings a different problem: accessing/reading/writing shared memory potentially from multiple threads can lead to unpredictable results. So (any kind of) access must be protected with some sort of synchronization (mutexes, atomics...)